# How i can re-write this in a manner it does provide the same output

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a mysql query like this:

```
SELECT 
    bp.id, 
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    blog_posts bp
JOIN
    tagged tg ON
        tg.taggable_id = bp.id
        AND tg.taggable_type = 'App\Storage\BlogPost'
JOIN
    tags t ON
        t.id = tg.tag_id
WHERE
    bp.user_id = 1
GROUP BY
    t.id
ORDER BY
    total DESC,
    t.count DESC
LIMIT
    3
```

and I got an error:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'example.bp.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

How i can re-write this in a manner it does provide the same output?

I work in MySQL 5.7.17 with Homestead Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're doing a `GROUP BY` everything you add to your `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clause needs to be in the `GROUP BY` clause, unless you're using an aggregate function such as MIN(), MAX(), SUM(), AVG(), etc.

In this case you have `t.count DESC` in your order by clause, writing the query like this will provide you with the desired result.

```
SELECT
    id,
    total
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            bp.id, 
            COUNT(*) AS total,
            MAX(t.count) count
        FROM
            blog_posts bp
        JOIN
            tagged tg ON
                tg.taggable_id = bp.id
                AND tg.taggable_type = 'App\Storage\BlogPost'
        JOIN
            tags t ON
                t.id = tg.tag_id
        WHERE
            bp.user_id = 1
        GROUP BY
            bp.id,
            t.id
        LIMIT
            3
    ) a
ORDER BY
    total DESC,
    `count` DESC
```

If you don't care if count is included in your final result then you can do this

```
SELECT 
    bp.id, 
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    MAX(t.count) count
FROM
    blog_posts bp
JOIN
    tagged tg ON
        tg.taggable_id = bp.id
        AND tg.taggable_type = 'App\Storage\BlogPost'
JOIN
    tags t ON
        t.id = tg.tag_id
WHERE
    bp.user_id = 1
GROUP BY
    bp.id,
    t.id
ORDER BY
    total DESC,
    t.count DESC
LIMIT
    3
```

Comment: i tried all your example but still got an error, 

`Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'example.bp.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: oops I just noticed you were group on t.id, not bp.id I'll update the queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused on two points - what you are trying to pull, and how you want the same result set (given you get no result set, at the moment)

The confusion comes in that you are reporting on bp.id, yet grouping on t.id.
the select and group should match in this case.  either select t.id, or group on bp.id, or select and group on BOTH - depending on the reporting requirements.

Further, although I believe MySQL does the optimization, it is better practice to use a count(1), unless you are specifically trying to avoid counting a keyed, null data row.

Hope that helps,
- John

Comment: What I'm trying to get is the top 3 tags used by a given author (user_id) in order to show the top used tags. What I expect in the end is just a list of blog pots (bp.id), I don't really need the counter if that would make the query more difficult... but if it's a combination of both would also be great. I can make this work on 5.6, but I couldn't figure out a way in 5.7.